# Internal hom in $(\infty,2)$-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories, infinity-categories

Let $X,Y$ be two $(\infty,2)$-categories, viewed as two fibrant objects in $\mathrm{Fun}(\Delta^{op},\mathrm{Set}_\Delta)$ with the complete Segal model structure (one uses the Joyal model structure on $\mathrm{Set}_\Delta$ to define this). It has been proved that the $(\infty,1)$-category 2-$\mathrm{Cat}$ of $(\infty,2)$-categories is Cartesian closed. The category of bisimplicial sets $\mathrm{Fun}(\Delta^{op}, \mathrm{Set}_\Delta)$ is also Cartesian closed.

My question is:

Does $Y^X$ in 2-$\mathrm{Cat}$ coincide with $Y^X$ in $\mathrm{Fun}(\Delta^{op}, \mathrm{Set}_\Delta)$, i.e. is the latter one fibrant?

If not, is there a reference about the relation between the two (more specific than saying the first $Y^X$ is a fibrant replacement of the latter $Y^X$)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes because the model structure on Fun(Δ^op, sSet)
is a cartesian model structure.
This follows from the fact that the Joyal model structure is cartesian,
and §10, §11 in Rezk's paper “A model for the homotopy theory of homotopy theory”.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri! I am not very familiar with model categories. Does Cartesian model structure implies something like $Y^X$ is fibrant, when $Y$ is fibrant and $X$ is cofibrant?

Comment: Yes, internal hom is a right Quillen functor in a cartesian model structure, which implies your claim.